# Continuous functions in metric space

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, metric-spaces

Let $f:R\rightarrow R$ be  continuous.

If  $f(0) >  0$,  show  that  $f(x)  >  0$  for  all  $x$  in  some  interval  $(-a,  a).$

Comment: what definition of continuity are you familiar with?

Comment: Think about what RyanK said.  In general, when stuck on a problem, it helps if you write down the definitions.

Comment: I am familiar with the delta-epsilon definition, also that of open sets, which is, if V is open, then f¯ (V) is also open

Comment: Hint: use the $\epsilon{-}\delta$ definition of continuity with $\epsilon = f(x)$.

Comment: Draw a picture, read the definition of continuity with $\epsilon-\delta$. From the picture, how can you choose an $\epsilon$ band so that the entire band is above zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f$ is continuous and $f(0) > 0$ then for any $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta$ small enough such that for all $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$  we have that $|f(x) - f(0)| \leq \epsilon$. Now we just need to choose $\epsilon = f(0)$. So then the $\delta$ that we choose will ensure that $f(x) > 0$ within this interval.